# Can subquery results be outdated?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have an query that uses a subquery to determine the id of the row to be inserted.  The goal is to increment each new row to the next multiple of **1000** allowing a generous gap between ids.  Is it possible that the id returned by the subquery could already be taken by another concurrent process?  Or is this subquery guaranteed to produce a unique id as if it were auto increment?

```
INSERT INTO `table`
SET id = (
    SELECT x.max_id
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) + 1000 as max_id
        FROM `table`
        WHERE id LIKE '%000'
    ) as x
)
```

Comment: If it was a normal subquery, I would say it's definitely atomic (assuming InnoDB). But I wonder if that holds true for a nested subquery.

Comment: Since this is technically a ["bulk insert"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-mode-consecutive), MySQL would by default lock the entire table. Unless it's smart enough to realize you're only selecting a single row.

Comment: hmm... I would think it's a simple insert but the definition does preclude a nested subquery.

Comment: To me, this *really* sounds like it could be a case of "solving the wrong problem."  What is your motivation, here?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - The IDs for a given block of 1000 (e.g., 2000,2001,2002) relate to one another in an application where human beings are involved.  It's simply easier for a person to look at a group of consecutive numbers and understand they are related.  There's no other reason and of course the database doesn't care.  It's strictly for aesthetic purposes.  The design could be changed to revert back to basic autoincrementing IDs, but I'd still be tasked with acquiring an 001, 002 ID etc for a given parent row which seems like it inevitably leads back to a query like this.

Comment: In general, I think it's bad design to depend on auto increment to follow any patterns, and can give unexpected results. For example, rejected inserts can result in sequence gaps, which may not look pretty but help ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I don't disagree with that - but the question still stands even if it's not the primary ID or autoincrement col.  I'm just trying to understand if it's possible that the subquery results are wrong at the moment that the parent query is executed, or are there mechanisms in place to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this just to set the interval between IDs, you should instead use:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1000;
```

This will make sure subsequent auto increment values are 1000 numbers apart. It's an enforcement on the engine level, so you don't have to worry about race conditions.

More information here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

Comment: thanks, but the id needs to be the next *multiple of 1000*, not 1000 apart.  Since other aspects of the application allow for ids in between the result should be something like this: 1000, 2000, 2001, 2002, 3000, 4000, 4001, etc.